# Sudden error in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

Getting this **error**

> ErrorException: Warning: Class __PHP_Incomplete_Class has no
>   unserializer in /var/www/myApp/src/symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache
>   line 915

I did not change anything in any file when suddenly started getting this error, went through some questions for this error and tried clearing the caches but it does not work, anyone has any idea?

Comment: clear cookie or session and try again.

Comment: This error pops up from time to time, fix it by removing the bootrstrap.php.cache file and run composer install again, one of the post-install-cmd calls is responsible for building the bootstrap file, and will generate a new, valid version

Comment: Could you pass around 20 lines from that error in `bootstrap.php.cache` on line 915? Maybe that would be helpful.

Comment: Apparently my cache:clear was not working correctly, it was giving an error which I missed : "Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 196608 bytes) ", so manually cleared the cache and it is working again